# ASP.Net MVC partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a menu (jquery-ui accordion with `Html.ActionLink` as menu options). How can I render a partial view in the main content `<div>` of the parent view, when selecting a menu option?

I can render the partial view, but not inside the main content `<div>`. Should I use `Html.ActionLink` in my menu options?

Comment: Is it giving any error .. if so can you please post it here ? If possible your code as well, that would help in determining the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe action links will help you, but they are a step in the right direction.

The pattern you've put to play thus far:

```
link: /articles/sports           Main Area
link: /articles/local_news
```

The two links along the left edge are your ActionLinks rendered to the page as normal links.  When clicked, they'll simply post back to the server and your entire page will be wiped out.

What you want to do is to hit the server for content and simply use that content within a container somewhere on your page.  To do this, you can render ordinary links with onclick handlers that post asynchronously to the server to retrieve partial content, which can then be used to set the main DIV's content.

For example, this can be declared in your View:

```
<a href="javascript:{Load('<%= Url.Action("Sports", "Articles") %>');}">
  Sports
</a>
```

Note the use of the `Url.Action` helper method to leverage route data to properly form outbound urls.

On the client (this uses jQuery, though any other library or JavaScript will do):

```
function Load(url)
{
  $.post
  (
    url, 
    null, 
    function(data)
    {
      $("#mainDIV").html(data);
    },
    "html"
  );
}
```

I'm using `$.post` instead of `$.get` to sidestep browser caching issues.